# Is there an open-source alternative to AVAudioPlayer which offers a callback when audio playback really started?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am making an app which is similar to flip book animation. It plays an audio track with AVAudioPlayer and starts animations which must start exactly at same time as audio starts. Tolerance is about +/- 100 msec.

I found AVPlayer as alternative which offers a callback but it is very complicated to use.